# iMac monitor colors are washed out after suspend in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mac, monitor

I managed to install Ubuntu on an old iMac a while ago, but when it wakes up from a suspend, the colours on the monitor are super washed out. I've looked for a few hours on the internet for a fix, but I didn't find anything that works. The washed out colours go away after a system restart but persist through a lightdm service restart. I've tried changing the brightness, but to no effect.

[image]
[Image of full colours after startup](https://i.imgur.com/8lRWSG2.jpg)
[image]
[Image of washed out colours after suspend](https://i.imgur.com/8lRWSG2.jpg)

Comment: This is a driver problem that cannot be solved at user level. There are several problems of this kind on a number of video cards.